# Multiple animations, only the first animation works in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two animations, even if the second animation is exactly the same as the first one, the second one won't work but the first one will.

```
class _TableAtHomeState extends State<TableAtHome> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late AnimationController _controller2;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  late Animation<double> _animation2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
       vsync: this);
    
    _animation = Tween(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 500.0,
    ).animate(_controller)..addListener((){
      setState(() {
        
      });
    });

    _controller2 = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
       vsync: this);

    _animation2 = Tween(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 500.0,
    ).animate(_controller2)..addListener((){
      setState(() {
        
      });
    });

     _controller.forward();
     _controller2.forward()
    
  }
  
  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _controller2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Another exception was thrown: LateInitializationError: Field '_animation2@30427762' has not been initialized.
```

So, I tried to remove `late` and that gave me another error.

The following code will work:

```
Positioned(
   left: width/2 - 25,
   top: _animation.value,
   child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50,width: 50,))
```

But the following code will raise an error (mentioned above):

```
Positioned(
   left: width/2 - 25,
   top: _animation2.value,
   child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50,width: 50,))
```

And i will like to do those animations one after the other not together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html) where you have multiple `AnimationController.`

Replace `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` with `TickerProviderStateMixin`

> [`SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html) only supports vending a single ticker. If you might have multiple `AnimationController` objects over the lifetime of the State, use a full [`TickerProviderStateMixin`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html) instead.

**Update:**

Provide unique for each `Positioned` widget and change position to see effect.

```dart
Positioned(
    key: const ValueKey("item 1"),
    left: width / 2 - 25,
    top: _animation.value,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.3),
      height: 150,
      width: 50,
    )),
Positioned(
    key: const ValueKey("item 2"),
    left: width / 2 - 25,
    top: _animation2.value,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(.3),
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
    ))
```

**Second Animation at the end of First animation**

replace `_controller2.forward();`  inside `_animation`

```dart
_animation = Tween(
  begin: 0.0,
  end: 500.0,
).animate(_controller)
  ..addListener(() {
    if (_animation.isCompleted) {
      _controller2.forward();
    }
    setState(() {});
  });
```

Comment: How can i do the 2 animations one after the other, rather than both at the same time

Comment: Check update, hope it will solve the issue, while both at same page, we can't see `animation`, item 1

Comment: at the end of 1st animation, you like to repeat it from initial position?

Comment: no i want to do the 2nd animation at the end of 1st animation

Comment: check update answer.  you can also use `addStatusListener` on 1st one.

Comment: This works, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240798/discussion-between-johan-jomy-and-yeasin-sheikh).